# AOP : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 can't find referenced pointcut

Tags: spring-aop

I am new to AOP. I got some problem like this.

```
package org.suman.Aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

@Aspect
public class LoginAspect {
    //@Before("execution(public String getName())")
    //@Before("execution(public String org.suman.Model.Triangle.getName())")
    //@Before("execution(* get*())")
    //@Before("execution(* get*(..))")
    //@Before("execution(* org.suman.Model.*.get*())")

    //@Before("execution(* get*())&& within(org.suman.Model.Circle)")
    @Before("execution(* get*())&& allCircle()")
    //@Before("allGetters() && allCircle()")
    public void LoginAdvice()
    {
        System.out.println("Advice run.. getMethod is called");
    }

    @Before("execution(* get*())")
    //@Before("allGetters()")
    public void SecondAdvice()
    {
        System.out.println("this is a second Advice");
    }
    @Pointcut("execution(* get*())")
    public void allGetters(){}

    //@Pointcut("execution (* * org.suman.Model.Circle.*(..))")
    @Pointcut("within(org.suman.Model.Circle)")
    public void allCircle(){}

}
```

when using pointcut, the method `allGetters()` to `LoginAdvice` method, if I use  `@Before("execution(* get*())")` then no error but if I use `@Before("allGetters()")` then gives error

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 can't find referenced pointcut allGetters

if I use `@Before("execution(* get*())&& within(org.suman.Model.Circle)")` instead of method name it works.

My xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">
    <!-- <context:annotation-config /> -->
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

    <bean name="triangle" class="org.suman.Model.Triangle">
        <property name="name" value="Triangle Name"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean name="circle" class="org.suman.Model.Circle">
        <property name="name" value="Circle name"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean name="shapeService" class="org.suman.Services.ShapeService"
        autowire="byName"></bean>
    <bean name="loginAspect" class="org.suman.Aspect.LoginAspect"></bean>

</beans>
```

Please solve the problem with pointcut by which it takes method

Comment: For those who came to this thread and none of the proposed solutions on this page worked, try taking a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21279716/error-at-0-cant-find-referenced-pointcut-annotation

Answer (score 28):

I had this problem - using @Pointcut on a 'placeholder' method was giving me the "can't find referenced pointcut" error.

Solved simply by updating the AspectJ libraries with the maven dependencies from this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

to this

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: For curious people why it's failing with 1.5.4 and working with 1.7.0: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15683358/253468

Comment: Pretty cool...its unusual but yeah changing to latest worked for me...thanks @Forge_7

Comment: i am using java8 , tried with aspectj 1.7.0 and 1.8.10 but still facing the issue

Answer (score 3):

I ran thjrough the same problem. Once i replace the aspectjweaver with the aspectjweaver-1.6.11.M2.jar version. Everything started working smoothly.

Answer (score 2):

The problem can also be caused by running an early access version of JDK9.

Maven might be preferring a newer version of Java over the JVM in `PATH`.

In my case I'm running Spring with Swagger2 via Maven on Ubuntu 15.04, and I have installed `java-8-oracle` and `java-9-oracle` (and a few more versions). My `java -version`, derived from `PATH`, says `1.8.0_72`, yet when I run Maven and change `/usr/bin/mvn` to `echo JAVA_HOME`, it shows to have selected `/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle`.

Exporting `JAVA_HOME` to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle` made Maven use the desired version of Java, and that made the problems with AOP weaving of pointcuts for Spring's dependency injection wiring go away.

Answer (score 2):

Use aspectjweaver and aspectjrt versions 1.8.10

Answer (score 1):

I also got similar issue with @Before advice not accepting @Pointcut method name as argument. I got this fixed by changing the dependencies version to:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.11</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjweaver -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.11</version>
</dependency>
```

Its working fine for me now.

Answer (score 1):

Encountered the same error in the different use case.

[image]

**UseCase :** Tried to call a pointcut which is present in different aspect class.

*logServicePointCut1() pointcut present in LogService*

```
package com.opensource.kms;
@Aspect
@Component
public class LogService {
    
    @Pointcut("execution(* com.opensource.kms.AccountService.my*(..))")
    public void logServicePointCut1() {
    }
}
```

*Try to call in SecurityService*

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class SecurityService {

    @Before("logServicePointCut1()")  /*Need to give fully Qualified name*/
    public void verifyUserBeforeSecurityService() {
        System.out.println("verifyUserBeforeSecurityService");
    }
}
```

**Solution:** Need to pass fully qualifed name **com.opensource.kms.LogService.logServicePointCut1(**)

Hope this would helpful for someone!!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to put another wildcard in front of:

```
@Pointcut("execution(* get*())")
```

change it to:

```
@Pointcut("execution(* *get*())")
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the aspectjeaver version to latest and deploy it...

Comment: Please improve your post by explaining why your post solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the aspectJWeaver version to be 1.6.x

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue because the project was compiled in Java 1.6, but tomcat server started in Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

It is the problem of dependencies. Following jars or dependencies of the exactly same version should be used to avoid such problems:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>aspectj</groupId>
<artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
<version>1.5.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
<artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
<version>1.8.10</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>asm</groupId>
<artifactId>asm</artifactId>
<version>3.3.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
<artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>cglib</groupId>
<artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
<version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: They are compatible with each other for AOP.

Answer (score 0):

Add this maven dependencies.
This will resolve your issue.

Change the version to **1.6.12**

Comment: What is "this maven dependencies"? Change version of what?

Answer (score 0):

Please use below maven dependencies - I hope it will work

1. [aspectjrt 1.8.14](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjrt)
2. [aspectjweaver 1.8.14](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjweaver)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.14</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.14</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was an error in the name of the method pointed out in pointcut in @AfterThrowing

[image]

All you had to do was adjust the method name to fit the note in AfterThrowing, and that's it!

[image]