# Is Spring 2.5.1 compatible with JDK 1.7

Tags: java, spring, spring-2.5

We are migrating from JDK 1.6 to 1.7 and we are using spring 2.5.1 version.
When starting the application i am getting the below error.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tivoliTransferManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/spring-managers.xml]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor] while setting bean property 'transactionInterceptor'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'transactionManager' while setting bean property 'transactionManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 can't find referenced pointcut addSingleUserToGroupPointCut
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:379)
>               at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:353)

Do we need to migrate the spring version as well ?

Also please find the content of spring.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

    <import resource="spring-managers.xml" />
    <import resource="spring-elementpermissions.xml" />
    <import resource="spring-scheduling.xml" />

    <context:annotation-config />
```

Comment: Please add your `spring.xml` to the question body.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AOP : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 can't find referenced pointcut](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10482563/aop-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-error-at-0-cant-find-referenced-poi)

Comment: please find the content of spring.xm

Comment: Please verify the aspectjweaver.jar and check the version

Comment: @KannanThangadurai yes the solution suggested worked i have upgraded the aspect jar and the issue is now resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error

> Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 can't  find referenced pointcut addSingleUserToGroupPointCut at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run

looks problem with the jar `aspectjweaver.jar`.

Please check jar file and configure the compatible **aspectjweaver.jar** version

Answer (score 3):

Spring 2.5 is not compatible with JDK 1.7 at least explicitly.It was originally built and tested on JDK 1.6  However i would think it should work with JDK 1.7  1.7 barring any big JDK breakages though.  Besides the error does not seem like a JDK version related issue at all.

I would recommend upgrading Spring to a later release because there has been a lot of improvements and new features introduced in later versions.